# How to make a doubleClick() on some coordinates (Webdriver io)?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, webdriver-io, double-click

I am writing tests in CoffeeScript using Webdriver.io and mocha. The code is processed using the CoffeeScript compiler.

I want to move the mouse cursor to some place on the canvas and make a doubleclick. **How can you set the coordinates for the doubleClick()?** The doubleClick function does not accept arguments with coordinates: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/doubleClick/.

I tried to move the cursor using the *moveTo()* command, and then *doubleClick()*, but the click is still carried out in the center of the canvas.

I tried to call the *click()* function twice instead of *doubleclick()*, but the results of one click remained on the canvas. Maybe *click()* is too slow, so two *click()* cannot replace one *doubleClick()*.

```
    schema = await $(consts.SCHEMA)
    await schema.click({x: 100, y: 100})
    await schema.click({x: 100, y: 100})
```

Comment: Are you using synchronous mode? Otherwise, you need to `await` the `moveTo` command before `doubleClick`. In any case, you should include some code in your question so that we can help answer it.

Comment: I use asynchronous mode. And I added the code at your request.